# Delphi Chromium - how get data of Ajax call when a button/link is clicked

Tags: ajax, delphi, chromium

I'm using Delphi Chromium component in an application to show web pages from a Web Application.
In these pages I have buttons that fire selective Ajax calls to Web Server.
I need the following thing:
when one of these buttons is clicked, after notification of event to 'host application' I should want from this notification to get data of Ajax request (and response too, if possible...) to do some processing on them from 'host application'.
Is it possible ?

Comment: I think it's simply a matter of calling the host application from javascript (in this case, from the callback that processes the AJAX response). The demos in delphichromiumembedded already include an example of how to do that, IIRC.

Comment: `cefclient.dpr`, see `TExtension` class

Comment: @TOndrej, thanks! That helped me a lot to understand. The extension (the `TCefv8HandlerOwn` class) is in fact just a JavaScript function which fires the `TCefv8HandlerOwn.Execute` (where you can get or set its parameters) when it's called from somewhere in the script.

Comment: @TLama Welcome, but I would rather say it's a way to have native (in this case, Pascal) code compiled in the host application callable from javascript.

Comment: Ok, thanks, but I don't understand what the extension TCefv8HandlerOwn  does in cefclient example... And how can I use it for my purposes (notify button click and get Ajax call's POST data) ?

Comment: @henry60 set a breakpoint in `TExtension.Execute`, run the app and navigate it to `javascript:cef.test.test_param="Hello, world!";alert(cef.test.test_param);`

Comment: Could you post your specific Ajax call workflow ? Right now I'm stucked with an simple Ajax showcase (I still can't understand the global objects created for registered extension code). Me and JavaScript won't be ever friends...

Comment: My Ajax call consists of a xml data exchange with server. I should want , in callback of Ajax call, Javascript send some data to host application so this one can do some action.

Answer (score 0):

> The extension (the TCefv8HandlerOwn class) is in fact just a JavaScript function which fires the TCefv8HandlerOwn.Execute (where you can get or set its parameters) when it's called from somewhere in the script.